# iis not working with domain user

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a problem which I cannot solve after some days. Simply, we have a web application which should run as a domain user (domain\user). We can do this in IIS (ver 8.5) manager in one server (statging) through application pool settings but when we do the same on another server (production) it is not working.

By not working I mean : If you browse that website and come back to the application pools tab, you see that it is stopped! and you receive `HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.` in the browser.

I have tried many things and solutions on SO but no success so far.

Comment: So you are using Windows Authentication ? Also check event logs you should see reason for crashes there and eventually disabling application pool.

Answer (score 0):

but when we do the same on another server (production) it is not working:

```
1.) Check Website Browsing Directory if enabled.
2.) Check Framework in application pools.
3.) Is your IIS set up correctly?
```

Hope it helps